# How to pass data to a Chart.js chart in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project and in this project you can type the amount of money you spent in a week(I have  Groceries, Shopping, Health and Home Needs inputs), and it calculates the total amount adding it to a component. Another feature inside this project is a chart made with Chart.js and it should display the amounts of money spended with groceries, shopping, health and home needs. But I'm having trouble with this part. I'm trying to pass the data stored in the controlled inputs by props, but the data is not being displayed in the chart. Can someone help me with that ? Here's the code:

```
 import React from "react";

import Header from "./Header";
import InputComponent from "./InputComponent";
import AmountCard from "./AmountCard";

import BillChart from "./BillsChart";

class SpendsApp extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   groceries: 10,
   shopping: 0,
   health: 0,
   houseNeeds: 0,
   total: 0,
   chartData: []
 };
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
 const { name, value } = e.target;
 this.setState({
   [name]: value
 });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
 const { groceries, shopping, health, houseNeeds } = this.state;

 const gSum = parseInt(groceries, 10);
 const sSum = parseInt(shopping, 10);
 const hSum = parseInt(health, 10);
 const hnSum = parseInt(houseNeeds, 10);

 this.setState({
   total: gSum + sSum + hSum + hnSum
 });
 e.preventDefault();
}

render() {
 return (
   <div className="main">
     <Header />
     <hr />
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <div className="input-flex">
           <InputComponent
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
             name="groceries"
             placeholder="Groceries"
           />
           <InputComponent
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
             name="shopping"
             placeholder="Shopping"
           />
           <InputComponent
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
             name="health"
             placeholder="Health"
           />
           <InputComponent
             handleChange={this.handleChange}
             name="houseNeeds"
             placeholder="Home"
           />
         </div>
         <button>Calculate</button>
       </form>
     </div>

     <AmountCard spent={this.state.total} />

     <BillChart spendings={[this.state.chartData]} />
   </div>
 );
}
}

export default SpendsApp;
```

here's the second one

```
 import React from "react";

import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

class BillsChart extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   chartData: {
     labels: ["Groceries", "Shopping", "Health", "House Needs"],
     datasets: [
       {
         label: "Amount Spent",
         backgroundColor: "green",
         hoverBackgroundColor: "green",
         hoverBorderWidth: 2,
         hoverBorderColor: "#000",
         data: [this.props.spendings]
       }
     ]
   }
 };
}

render() {
 return <Bar onClick={this.props.handleClick} data={this.state.chartData} />;
}
}

export default BillsChart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a method upside the render() in BillsChart

```
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.spendings !== this.props.spendings) {

     let {chartData} = this.state;
     chartData.datasets[0].data = this.props.spendings
     this.setState({chartData});

    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i added it and made the other necessary fixes, it worked the way I wanted it to be, thanks a lot man!

Comment: You are welcome @GabrielTisoVinhasdeBrito. Please mark my answer as accepted and vote by pressing the up arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in your `SpendsApp` component you have never changed the value of the chartData state. You change the number of the total and the other properties but you never change the value of the chartData you pass.

You can have something like that

```
 //code....
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      groceries: 10,
      shopping: 0,
      health: 0,
      houseNeeds: 0,
      total: 0,
      chartData: []
    }
 }



handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const { groceries, shopping, health, houseNeeds } = this.state;

   const gSum = parseInt(groceries, 10);
   const sSum = parseInt(shopping, 10);
   const hSum = parseInt(health, 10);
   const hnSum = parseInt(houseNeeds, 10);

  // chartData array elements should be ordered as in your labels in the <BillsChart/>
  // labels: ["Groceries", "Shopping", "Health", "House Needs"] as you have it
  this.setState({
      total: gSum + sSum + hSum + hnSum,
      chartData: [gSum, sSum, hSum, hnSum] 
  });
}
```

Also another thing is that instead of this:

```
<BillChart spendings={[this.state.chartData]} />
```

try this

```
<BillChart spendings={this.state.chartData} />
```

The reason for that is because, if you passed correctly the values in the array you will end up in with a two-dismentional array here `data: [this.props.spendings]` .

If you have already mounted your component you should use `componentDidUpdate()` to change the state of the `<BillChart/>`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.spendings !== this.props.spendings) {
     let chartData = this.state.chartData;

     chartData.datasets[0].data = this.props.spendings
     this.setState({chartData});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the prop `spending` on your BillChart in the render, which is passing an empty array as a prop to the component.

```
this.state = {
   groceries: 10,
   shopping: 0,
   health: 0,
   houseNeeds: 0,
   total: 0,
   chartData: []
 };


 <BillChart spendings={[this.state.chartData]} />
```

So when you setState on chartData in your BillsChart component it is setting the data property to that empty array.

```
this.state = {
   chartData: {
     labels: ["Groceries", "Shopping", "Health", "House Needs"],
     datasets: [
       {
         label: "Amount Spent",
         backgroundColor: "green",
         hoverBackgroundColor: "green",
         hoverBorderWidth: 2,
         hoverBorderColor: "#000",
         data: [this.props.spendings]
       }
     ]
   }
 };
```

You need to setState of chartData to something besides an empty array before you pass it as a prop.

Comment: this doesn't create any problem. When you `import BillChart from "./BillsChart";`, you are defining a new variable named  BillChart or name it whatever you want.

Comment: ok yeah i thought so, i've just never seen anyone use different names like that.  super confusing.    I'll take a look and see what else it might be.

Comment: @AliHayder Updated my answer